# Is it safe to deallocate a BSTR on a different thread than it was allocated on?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, com

If I call a COM method that returns a `BSTR` on one thread, is it safe to call `SysFreeString()` on that `BSTR` from another thread? Once the COM call has finished, I won't be using the `BSTR` on the first thread anymore, so there shouldn't be any concurrency issues. However given how COM is with threads, I'm not sure if `SysFreeString()` relies on the `BSTR` being allocated on the same thread or not.

Sample code:

```
BSTR value = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = pComObject->DoSomething(&value);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    return hr;
}

std::thread t([value] {
    // do something with value
    SysFreeString(value);
});
t.detach();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN does not say it explicitly, however there are still references that `Sys*String` functions are using OS implementation of `IMalloc`, through [`CoGetMalloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693395) and friends.

> Automation may cache the space allocated for BSTRs. This speeds up the SysAllocString/SysFreeString sequence. However, this may also cause IMallocSpy to assign leaks to the wrong memory user because it is not aware of the caching done by Automation.

COM implementation [is thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678425):

> Generally, you should not implement IMalloc, instead using the COM implementation, which is guaranteed to be thread-safe in managing task memory. You get a pointer to the COM task allocator object's IMalloc through a call to the CoGetMalloc function.

All together, it is okay to free string from another thread.

Comment: BSTR was specifically engineered for this task. Calling SysAllocString and SysFreeString on different threads are routinely performed in distributed COM servers. Actually, in case of a function that returns a string to an [out] BSTR** parameter, a local copy is allocated and deallocated again after marshalling.

Comment: Indeed, BSTRs coming from marshaling are likely to be allocated on the same thread too and this part/reference does not explain that passing BSTR between threads is fine. I am pretty sure that the API is totally thread safe or otherwise it would cause enormous number of problems. MSDN should have just mentioned it clearly that the API is thread safe and pointers can travel between threads without restrictions.

Comment: As far as my memory serves me, Don Box explains this in his book "Essential COM"